# HTML Dom code not running

Tags: php, dom, server

I am trying to create a script that extracts text from a website table and displays it via php. When I run it on this address :

http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50

It turns out empty. Is there something wrong with the code? And how can I fix / improve it?

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
// Start a cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// Set options for the cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50'); // target
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // provide a user-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow any redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the result
// Execute the cURL fetch
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the resource
curl_close($ch);
// Output the results
echo $result;
function scraping() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50');

    // get article block
    if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
    foreach($html->find('/html/body/table') as $article) {
        // get title
        $item['titlu'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div', 0)->plaintext);
        // get body
        $item['tr2'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr3'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr4'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr5'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr6'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr7'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr8'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[8]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr9'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[9]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr10'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[10]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr11'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[11]', 0)->plaintext);
         $item['tr12'] = trim($article->find('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[12]', 0)->plaintext);
        $ret[] = $item;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;}
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!
$ret = scraping();

foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo $v['titlu'].'<br>';
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr2'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr3'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr4'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr5'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr6'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr7'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr8'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr9'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr10'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr11'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['tr12'].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because in foreach you use result of finding `/html/body/table` you should not use full path but ask:

   `$item['titlu'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[1]/td/div', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr2'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[2]', 0)->plaintext);`

and so on...

2. To your curl works, you need move

   `$ch = curl_init();`

before first `curl_setopt`

Comment: Same result, could it be that the webpage doesn't allow scraping? I've tested the script on other pages and it works, if so how can i bypass this?

Comment: This result i receive after changing your code. Before was blank. 
`Detalii oferta : lucrator comercial
Cod identificare oferta      50/01/1150001435/1
Judet      Bucuresti
Agentia locala     Sector 1`

Comment: I've change 4 first assignments. As you see in them there are results. Others are black

Comment: could you send me a jsfiddle? i might have missed something. thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I forgot :( I add  to answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t0uuabh2/ is this right? also the link to the server i am using to test the script http://pied.ro/test/ut.php

Comment: I can't use it. I try your script on my local server. It works ok.

Comment: Why you write your code to CSS part. I think it is not correct

Comment: you need to give me the link to the updated jsfiddle

Comment: I overwrited  code here jsfiddle.net/t0uuabh2 and say update. It is not enough ?